# Xamarin forms, change Target Framework

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I created a basic Xamarin forms project, the project was automatically set to the Android 8.1 (Oreo) target framework.
If i launch the project into an Android 8.1(Oreo) emulator it works.
Now i want to change the Target Framework to Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) and it didn't work. I receive error messages about the incompatibility with the Xamarin.Android.Support.V7 libraries as you can see in the screenshot.
How can downgrade the target framework or how can i create a new xamarin project directly with the Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) Api ?

[image]

Comment: If you are trying to change the "compile" target (vs the min. API or runtime API of the APK), you would have to use older versions of the Android Support libraries. Typically with Xamarin, you would use the *Xamarin* compile/framework target to the latest version and then set the *Android* min/max/target API versions to the device APIs that you are supporting at runtime, now you can use the latest versions of the Android support libraries at compile time.

Comment: To complement @SushiHangover's answer, please read through the following: https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd (Target Framework is synonymous with `compileSdkVersion` in this case). `minSdkVersion (lowest possible) <= targetSdkVersion == compileSdkVersion (latest SDK)`

Comment: Plus one for the Medium post, perhaps the clearest description of the various targets I've read... @JonDouglas